# Arranging First and Last Names in data

Tags: names

Are there guidelines or best practice for formatting first and last names displayed in gridviews? Is it better to display the first name first or the last name first?

Answer (score 0):

There is no universally accepted convention; the ordering of parts of personal names depends on the culture.

You can read more about this here: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

Then again, from a user-interface perspective, if the user is more likely to sort by the last name it should come before the first name.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I've always found it better to show the surname first, followed by given name. Perhaps it's possible for you to have two separate columns if sorting on either one could be useful.

Bear in mind, if this is appropriate to your task, that the first/last names are not always the given name/surname in certain cultures so it's better to refer to them as given/surnames.